# Simple systems are the "smallest"

Tags: finite-groups, reflection, coxeter-groups

Let $\Phi$ be a root system of a finite reflection group $W$. Let $\Delta$ be a simple system in $\Phi$. I want to prove that $\Delta$ is "the smallest" set which generates $W$, more precisely: There is no proper subset $A$ of $\Delta$ which generates $W$.

I start with the following: suppose well, then we can find $\alpha\in\Delta\setminus A$ such that $s_{\alpha}$ is not needed as a generator. But now? Is the goal to prove that $A=\Delta$ or how to get the contradiction?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\Delta$ irreducible, otherwise take components.
The elements of $\Delta$ that are combinations of basic roots from $A$ form a root system   $\Phi'\subset \Phi$. The reflection $(s_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ generate its Weyl group $W'$. Let $\beta \ne \alpha$, $\beta \in \Delta'$. We have $W' \cdot \beta \subset \Phi'$. Note that $\Phi' \ne \Phi$ since $\alpha$ is not an integral combination of the other basic roots. However, $W\cdot \beta = \Phi$ since $\Delta$ is irreducible. We conclude that $W'\ne W$.

Comment: Why do you say integral span? It is not assumed that the group is affine.

Comment: We know that any root in $\Delta$ is a positive or negative integral combination of elements of $\Delta$. Take only those involving elements of $A$. I will make that clear in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Can you say me how to work with the hint that we can find $w\in W$ with $w(-\alpha)\in\Delta$?